Do iterated factorials or iterated exponents grow faster?
This is purely out of curiosity and I'm not quite at the point in calculus where I know how to prove either for myself...
Given $$n^{n^{n^{n^n}}}$$ and $$(((n!)!)!)!$$
As n approaches infinity, which iterated operator grows faster, given that they're both iterated the same number of times.
($n^{n^{n^{...^{n}}}}$ (with i layers of exponentiation). and $(((n!)!)...)!$ (with i layers of factorials)
All I've really been able to find in Desmos due to computational ability is what looks like the factorial function grows slower just by delay, reaching $10^{300}$ (Desmos maximum) around $x = 2.18$ while the exponents reached $10^{300}$ around $x = 1.75$
Desmos Screenshot
Desmos Screenshot of Log

It's a confusing problem statement because you introduce both the argument $n$ and the number of iterates as variables.  You could create a meaningful comparison only by fixing one or the other.

You'll find Wolfram Alpha handles numbers a bit larger than this very well.

Too long for a comment.
Considering that $n$ is a real number, let us have a look at the ratio
$$R(n)=\frac{n^{n^{n^{n^n}}} } {(((n!)!)!)! }$$
It is smaller than $1$ for $0<n<1$ and goes through a minimum value of $0.597048$ for $n=0.273072$.
For $n>1$, it increases so fast that I prefer to put a table of the inverse
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 R(n) & n \\
 10^1 &  1.74629 \\
 10^2 & 1.87642 \\
 10^3 & 1.94135 \\
 10^4 & 1.98326 \\
 10^5 & 2.01369 \\
 10^6 & 2.03734 \\
 10^7 & 2.05656 \\
 10^8 & 2.07266 \\
 10^9 & 2.08648 \\
 10^{10} & 2.09855 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I didn't think to test it with ratios, that's a much better method, thank you.

@ææ When you face big numbers or approximation or asymptotics, the ratio gives a good vision of the problem. Could you repeat your calculation and add a plot for the ratio ?

I fiddled with Wolfram Alpha instead for a bit and confirmed the tetration grows much faster as n approached infinity for any given iteration count greater than 1 using a ratio of the two functions.

@ææ. Make me a favor : plot $$\log \left(\log \left(\log \left(\log
\left(n^{n^{n^n}}\right)\right)\right)\right)-\log (\log (\log
(\log ((((n!)!)!)!))))$$ and add it to your post. I would like to "see" it (I am blind).

I added it for you.
